# Haskell user defined data types

Tags: haskell, types, haskell-platform

I want define kind of R data as rational numbers, where R is (denominator,numerator) and I defined as:

```
data R = R {n::Int,
            d::Int} deriving Show
```

Now I tried to do a function that given two arguments(a list of R and a R) and returns a list with the equivalents of R. I try this, but give me a error of types.

```
equivalentes' :: [R] -> R -> [R]
equivalentes' [] _ = []
equivalentes' (x:xs) r
    | (n x `mod` n r == 0) && (d x `mod` d r == 0) = (R(d n)x): equivalentes' xs r
    | otherwise = equivalentes' xs r
```

My idea is to return something like this:

```
> equivalentes'[R(2,4),R(3,5),R(4,8)] (R(1,2))
                   [R (2,4),R (4,8)]
```

Comment: @Cirdec ` Couldn't match expected type `R' with actual type `R -> Int' ...`

Comment: You have shown us the definition for a function named `equivalentes'` (with a `'` at the end), but its implementation and your example invocation refer to `equivalentes` (without a `'`).  Where is the definition of this other function?

Comment: @jwodder You're right! I've fixed it. That happens when I copy and paste

Comment: When you get this working, you might be surprised by the result of `equivalentes [R 4 9] (R 2 3)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the expression

```
R (d n) x : equivalentes' xs r
```

And specifically with

```
d n
```

The `n` function has type `R -> Int`, as does the `d` function, but you've passed `n` to `d` as its argument.  Maybe you meant something like

```
R (d x) x
```

But since `x` has type `R`, this also wouldn't work, so you could have meant

```
R (d x) (n x)
```

or something similar.

---

On a different note, you can't do `R (1, 2)`, because `(1, 2)` is a tuple of two `Int`s, not just two separate `Int`s.  you could do instead `R 1 2`, or `uncurry R (1, 2)` if you really wanted to use tuples.

Comment: The fact that this kind of errors is hard to spot is why one shouldn't use single-letter names for fields (or anything else in global scope, for that matter).

Comment: @Rhymoid I would even view this as an additional reason why you shouldn't, but more importantly you should use descriptive names just so people know what the code is doing at a glance.  I'm assuming that this could have been instead `data Ratio = Ratio { numerator :: Int, denominator :: Int }`, but only after looking at the code to figure out what OP was trying to do.  Had similar names been used to begin with, there would have been no confusion.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, both functions and constructors are applied by juxtaposition. For example `f x` is the function `f` applied to the argument `x`. `f x y` is the function `f` applied to `x`, with the result applied to `y`. You can think of `f x y` as `f` applied to two arguments, `x` and `y`. You don't need parenthesis for function or constructor application, for example `f (x y)` means something different - in this case `x` is being applied to `y`, and `f (x, y)` means the function `f` applied to the tuple `(x, y)`.

For your code, you need to use

- `R 2 4` instead of `R(2,4)`
- `R (n x) (d x)` instead of `R(d n)x`

When we make these syntax changes, `equivalentes` would be written as

```
equivalentes :: [R] -> R -> [R]
equivalentes [] _ = []
equivalentes (x:xs) r
    | (n x `mod` n r == 0) && (d x `mod` d r == 0) = R (n x) (d x): equivalentes xs r
    | otherwise = equivalentes xs r
```

And your example would be written as

```
equivalentes [R 2 4,R 3 5,R 4 8] (R 1 2)
```